# Cómo puedo sacar el texto dentro de un <il> al hacerle click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Mi problema es que quiero sacar el texto que tiene dentro de un `<li>` cada vez que lo hacemos click.

```js
$("#lista").click(function (event) {
   alert($("#lista li").html());
})
```

```html
<!-- jQuery  -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="container" id="pagination_list">
    <ul class="pagination" id="lista">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Cuando lo ejecuto me muestra el primer elemento y no sobre el que hacemos click.

Answer (score 3):

Para eso tienes que usar [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```js
 $("#lista li").click(function (event) {
    console.log($(this).text());
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pagination" id="lista">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hay que tener cuidado con la función `jQuery#text` porque no solo extrae el texto del elemento, si no también **los de sus nodos hijos**.

Una forma sencilla de obtener el texto solo del elemento padre es primero clonando el elemento, luego eliminar los hijos y posteriormente, obtener el texto del elemento padre.

```
$("#lista li").clone().children().remove().end().text();
```